# Modificar los datos de una columna en un DataFrame, utilizando sentencias condicionales

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Seguramente es una tontería, pero no la pillo. Disponemos del DataFrame siguiente.

```
dicc = {'Close': {'2014-04-09': 100.49,
  '2014-04-10': 98.95,
  '2014-04-11': 97.85,
  '2014-04-14': 98.73,
  '2014-04-15': 98.81},
 'fear_metric': {'2014-04-09': 31.0,
  '2014-04-10': 31.0,
  '2014-04-11': 21.0,
  '2014-04-14': 23.0,
  '2014-04-15': 23.0},
 'rating': {'2014-04-09': 'nan',
  '2014-04-10': 'nan',
  '2014-04-11': 'nan',
  '2014-04-14': 'nan',
  '2014-04-15': 'nan'}}

df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicc)


        Close   fear_metric     rating
2014-04-09  100.49  31.0    nan
2014-04-10  98.95   31.0    nan
2014-04-11  97.85   21.0    nan
2014-04-14  98.73   23.0    nan
2014-04-15  98.81   23.0    nan
```

y quiero modificar los valores de la columna **'rating'**, dependiendo del valor que exista en la columna **'fear_metric'**
Con este fin construyo el script siguiente.

## Preparar DataFrame

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['fear_metric'] <= 25  :
        row['rating'] = 'extreme_fear'
        
    if (row['fear_metric'] > 25)| (row['fear_metric'] < 50 ) :
        row['rating'] = 'fear'
        
    if row['fear_metric'] == 50  :
        row['rating'] = 'neutral'
        
    if (row['fear_metric'] > 50) | (row['fear_metric'] <= 75)  :
        row['rating'] = 'greed'
        
    if row['fear_metric'] > 75  :
        row['rating'] = 'extreme_greed'



df.head
```

Me devuelve

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of              Close  fear_metric rating
2014-04-09  100.49         31.0    nan
2014-04-10   98.95         31.0    nan
2014-04-11   97.85         21.0    nan
2014-04-14   98.73         23.0    nan
2014-04-15   98.81         23.0    nan>
```

Donde se aprecia claramente que no está haciendo lo esperado. ¿Cuál puede ser el error?. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Al trabajar con `dataframes` es recomendable utilizar los métodos/funciones disponibles ya que optimizan el cálculo para filas y columnas (Hay que intentar evitar iterar con ciclos las filas/columnas).

La forma eficiente para poder realizar esto sería utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) ya que puede evaluar fila por fila todo el `dataframe` y aplicar alguna función que puede o no involucrar el valor de la fila pero en otras columnas.

Teniendo el siguiente `dataset` (Modifiqué los valores de tu pregunta para mostrar por lo menos un elemento de cada "categoría")

|  | Close | fear_metric | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-04-09 | 100.49 | 31 | nan |
| 2014-04-10 | 98.95 | 50 | nan |
| 2014-04-11 | 97.85 | 21 | nan |
| 2014-04-14 | 98.73 | 65 | nan |
| 2014-04-15 | 98.81 | 85 | nan |

Podemos definir una función que nos devuelva la "categoría" (Hay otras funciones de pandas para crear categorías [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical) y sub grupos [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), per no las podemos utilizar porque en este caso tienes "rangos" y al mismo tiempo tienes un valor puntual "50" por lo que no se puede realizar con esas funciones, por eso definimos una función para obtener las categorías):

```
def cat(x):
    if x <= 25  :
        return 'extreme_fear'
        
    if 25 < x < 50:
        return 'fear'
        
    if x == 50  :
        return 'neutral'
        
    if 50 < x <= 75:
        return 'greed'
        
    if x > 75  :
        return 'extreme_greed'
```

Y lo único que hay que hacer es aplicar esa función en la columna `fear_metric` y asignar su resultado en la columna `rating`

```
df['rating'] = df['fear_metric'].apply(lambda x: cat(x))
```

Esto devuelve:

|  | Close | fear_metric | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-04-09 | 100.49 | 31 | fear |
| 2014-04-10 | 98.95 | 50 | neutral |
| 2014-04-11 | 97.85 | 21 | extreme_fear |
| 2014-04-14 | 98.73 | 65 | greed |
| 2014-04-15 | 98.81 | 85 | extreme_greed |

Si lo quisieras hacer con tu ciclo `for` lo que hace falta es que debes modificar la fila del `dataframe` original utilizando `loc` o `iloc` (Por cierto, tus rangos 25-50 y 50-75 deberían llevar `&` no `|`, lo corregí en el ejemplo siguiente)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['fear_metric'] <= 25  :
        df.loc[index,'rating'] = 'extreme_fear'
        
    if (row['fear_metric'] > 25) & (row['fear_metric'] < 50 ) :
        df.loc[index,'rating']  = 'fear'
        
    if row['fear_metric'] == 50  :
        df.loc[index,'rating']  = 'neutral'
        
    if (row['fear_metric'] > 50) & (row['fear_metric'] <= 75)  :
        df.loc[index,'rating']  = 'greed'
        
    if row['fear_metric'] > 75  :
        df.loc[index,'rating']  = 'extreme_greed'
```

Comment: Gracias. En mi ruta de autoaprendizaje, me toca dar un pasito más y estudiar las funciones que me indicas: pandas.Categorical, pandas.cut y pandas.DataFrame.apply. Hasta ahora, no utilizaba iterrows, sino for i in..., con loc. Pero descubrí iterrows y quise aplicarlo, pensando que no necesitaba loc.

Comment: No hay de qué, yo no llevo mucho con pandas, algo que me ayudo es leer preguntas pasadas e intentar darles solución, luego comparar mi solución con las aceptadas